# Unable to run code of Reactjs code on live server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, react-redux

1. I am a newbie and wrote this code from a tutorial. This code is not giving "Hello World" output when I open it with live server

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <title>Learning React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
      class App extends React.component {
        render() {
          return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello World");
        }
      }
      ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(App, null),
        document.getElementById("root")
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's probably worth looking at something like create-react-app to get you started

Comment: It's `React.Component`, not `React.component`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`React.component` needs to be with capital c: `React.Component`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <title>Learning React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
      class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return React.createElement("div", null, "Hello World");
        }
      }
      ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(App, null),
        document.getElementById("root")
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```